# Last 4 bytes of HTTP response come after >30s delay

Tags: networking, performance, http, tcp

I'm encountering a weird error with one of my websites. No matter which page I'm trying to display, about 3 out of 5 cases and up loading in no less than 30 seconds...

When loading the website with telnet one can see that the entire webpage is sent instantly, but the last few bytes (usually 4, them being `tml>`) come after a huge delay of >30 seconds.

Here's a wireshark dump of the connection:

https://hub.sealcode.org/file/download/yoeemk4oiva4npcbpytl/PHID-FILE-ioekrfrv4pbwyqjamgmp/delay_anon.pcapng

EDIT:

It happens in all clients, including telneting to port 80.

The backend runs on a shared hosting server, so I'm not sure about the exact OS version - i only know it's Linux-based. The server uses PHP 5.4 with FPM

Comment: You are not giving enough details. What OS and HTTP server versions? What clients are you using? Did you try with more than one? From different locations? Are the pages static or generated on the fly?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thank you for your comment, I've updated the question with some more details

Comment: PHP 5.4 is obsoleted since 3 years. You can not upgrade? Do you have the same problem for a static page on the same server when queried by the same client? If so, you have the culprit...